# Passing string included : signs to -Replace Variable in powershell script

Tags: string, powershell, replace, literals

```
$FilePath = 'Z:\next\ResourcesConfiguration.config'
$oldString = 'Z:\next\Core\Resources\'
$NewString = 'G:\PublishDir\next\Core\Resources\'
```

Any Idea how can you replace a string having : sign in it.  I want to change the path in a config file. Simple code is not working for this. tried following

```
(Get-Content $original_file) | Foreach-Object {
 $_ -replace $oldString, $NewString
 } | Set-Content $destination_file
```

Comment: Please provide desired output for input strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Replace operator takes a regular expression pattern and '\' is has a special meaning in regex, it's the escape character. You need to double each backslash, or better , use the escape method:

```
$_ -replace [regex]::escape($oldString), $NewString
```

Alterntively, you can use the string.replace method which takes a string and doesn't need a special care:

```
$_.Replace($oldString,$NewString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$oldString = [REGEX]::ESCAPE('Z:\next\Core\Resources\')
```

You need escape the pattern to search for.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$Source = 'Z:\Next\ResourceConfiguration.config'
$Dest = 'G:\PublishDir\next\ResourceConfiguration.config'
$RegEx = "Z:\\next\\Core\\Resources"
$Replace = 'G:\PublishDir\next\Core\Resources'

(Get-Content $FilePath) | Foreach-Object { $_ -replace $RegEx,$Replace } | Set-Content $Dest
```

The reason that your attempt wasn't working is that `-replace` expects it's first parameter to be a Regular Expression. Simply put, you needed to escape the backslashes in the directory path, which is done by adding an additional backspace (`\\`). It expects the second parameter to be a string, so no changes need to be done there.

Comment: The answers using `[regex]::escape` are, of course, much more succinct and easier to manage down the road.